# Parallel task execution at different time

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I have console app which performs a couple of tasks in parallel. In my case the important part is that i want the tasks to complete at the same time. I know how long each task is going to take. So the idea is to delay somehow every task in the Parallel.ForEach with custom time delay per task so they all finish at the same time and in the end all the tasks will complete approximately at the same time as the one which takes most time.

Example:

```
interface IService
{
    void DoWork();
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var services = new List<IService>();
        services.Add(new ServiceA());//Takes 500ms to DoWork()
        services.Add(new ServiceB());//Takes 1000ms to DoWork()
        services.Add(new ServiceC());//Takes 5000ms to DoWork()

        Parallel.ForEach(services, z =>
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            z.DoWork();
            Console.WriteLine($"Ready for {sw.Elapsed}");
        });
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Ready for 00:00:00.5006837
Ready for 00:00:01.0002284
Ready for 00:00:05.0010202
Press any key to continue . . .
```

How to modify the code so the output will look like:

```
Ready for 00:00:05.5006837
Ready for 00:00:05.0002284
Ready for 00:00:05.0010202
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I guess the most obvious solution would be to distinguish which Service is z in the loop and add custom Thread.Sleep before calling z.DoWork(), but I am looking for smarter solution.

Comment: You can't simply guarantee that all tasks will complete at the same time. However you can wait for them all to complete before continuing; look at the Task.WaitAll() documentation.

Comment: Don't use multiple entirely different parallelization paradigms at the same time.  *Either* use tasks, *or* use the `Parallel` class.  Don't use both.  You also shouldn't use the `Task` constructor.  If you want to create a `Task` that runs some function in a thread pool thread then use `Task.Run` instead to create already started tasks.

Comment: I don't want them to complete at the same time but approximately same time with a difference of some milliseconds

Comment: @Servy this is just example. In my real code I don't use tasks. In the Parallel.ForEach I am pulling data from different sources, but the idea is the same. I don't want to pull the data from the fastest sources because of the time i receive the data from the slowest source it will be redundant.

Comment: @xxbbcc if you read again my question you will see that Thread.Sleep is just for the sake of the example. In the real case those Sleeps are time consuming operations

Comment: @IIvanov If that is the case, you should just update your question and replace the Sleep calls with a comment that says time-consuming work. Your question is confusing.

Comment: @IIvanov If you're not actually using `Task`, then don't use it here.  Create a *representative* example.

Comment: Just create all your tasks and then do a `Task.WhenAll` to wait on all of them.

Comment: I will update the question sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @IIvanov _I don't want to pull the data from the fastest sources because of the time i receive the data from the slowest source it will be redundant_, can you elaborate? Sounds like why even bother with the known fastest sources if your just going to make them wait? Can you detail what you really want to accomplish, could this be an [XY Probloem](http://xyproblem.info/)?

Comment: Is it important that *some parts* (the last parts, by the sound of things) are happening at approximately the *same* time? If so, it may be that breaking these processes down into discrete steps and then using [`Barrier`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.barrier(v=vs.110).aspx) to allow them to work in lock-step may be what you're looking for.

Comment: @JSteward I am working on ticket re-seller platform. When I sell tickets for a specific event I am connecting to multiple sources for tickets (other re-sellers). When customer comes to my website and asks for 110 tickets I am actually buying them from multiple sources because not everybody has 110. So there are services which responds immediately (lets call it ServiceA) and others which have up to 3 minutes delay (ServiceB). If I call ServiceB now and ServiceA after 3 min I will have actual information for the capacity of each re-seller.

Comment: If you're actually *buying* the tickets from these services, all the delay does is introduce the possibility that service A sells the necessary tickets during that 3 minutes of wait. If you're just showing capacity, the information is out of date before you've even attempted to show it to the user so in no way guarantees they'll be able to buy enough tickets when they attempt to buy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help!  So this is what i wanted to achieve. All the services finish their job at the same time. Is this the right way of doing it?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ServiceA a = new ServiceA();
        ServiceB b = new ServiceB();
        ServiceC c = new ServiceC();

        int maxDelay = 3000;
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

        Task taskA = Task.Delay(maxDelay - a.ResponseTime).ContinueWith(x =>
          {
              a.DoWork();
              Console.WriteLine($"taskA ready for {sw.Elapsed}");
          });

        Task taskB = Task.Delay(maxDelay - b.ResponseTime).ContinueWith(x =>
          {
              b.DoWork();
              Console.WriteLine($"taskB ready for {sw.Elapsed}");
          });

        Task taskC = Task.Delay(maxDelay - c.ResponseTime).ContinueWith(x =>
        {
            c.DoWork();
            Console.WriteLine($"taskC ready for {sw.Elapsed}");
        });

        taskA.Wait();
        taskB.Wait();
        taskC.Wait();

        Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
    }
}

class ServiceA
{
    public int ResponseTime { get => 500; }
    public void DoWork() => Thread.Sleep(500);
}

class ServiceB
{
    public int ResponseTime { get => 1000; }
    public void DoWork() => Thread.Sleep(1000);
}

class ServiceC
{
    public int ResponseTime { get => 3000; }
    public void DoWork() => Thread.Sleep(3000);
}
```

Output:

```
taskA ready for 00:00:03.0084344
taskC ready for 00:00:03.0102184
taskB ready for 00:00:03.0102588
```

*Thread.Sleep(x) represents some time consuming operations.